# Java static arraylist initialization issue

Tags: java, arraylist

**This issue happens to me only in production and am myself not able to reproduce it during testing/development**

I have a class containing lot of static variables.

```
public class MyClass {

 private static final ArrayList<String> MY_LIST = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("DCNC", "DJPC", "DKRC", "DTHC", "DTWC", "DILC", "DALC", "DSEC", "DTRC", "DZAC", "DARC", "DCOC", "DRUC", "DMYC", "DMXC", "DPKC", "DIDC", "DBRC", "DNPC", "DJOC", "DLKC", "DVNC", "DKHC", "DLAC"));
 public static final HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> MY_MAP = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

 static {
     MY_MAP.put("test1", MY_LIST);
     MY_MAP.put("test2", MY_LIST);
     MY_MAP.put("test3", MY_LIST);
     MY_MAP.put("test4", MY_LIST);
     MY_MAP.put("test5", MY_LIST);
     MY_MAP.put("test6", MY_LIST);

 }

 private static final ArrayList<String> MY_SECOND_LIST = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("DCNC", "DJPC", "DKRC", "DTHC", "DTWC", "DILC", "DALC", "DSEC", "DTRC", "DZAC", "DARC", "DCOC", "DRUC", "DMYC", "DMXC", "DPKC", "DIDC", "DBRC", "DNPC", "DJOC", "DLKC", "DVNC", "DKHC", "DLAC"));
 private static final ArrayList<String> MY_THIRD_LIST = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("DJPC", "DKRC", "DTHC", "DTWC", "DILC", "DALC", "DSEC", "DTRC", "DZAC", "DARC", "DCOC", "DRUC", "DMYC", "DMXC", "DPKC", "DIDC", "DBRC", "DNPC", "DJOC", "DLKC", "DVNC", "DKHC", "DLAC"));
 private static final ArrayList<String> MY_FOURTH_LIST = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("DCNC", "DKRC", "DTHC", "DTWC", "DILC", "DALC", "DSEC", "DTRC", "DZAC", "DARC", "DCOC", "DRUC", "DMYC", "DMXC", "DPKC", "DIDC", "DBRC", "DNPC", "DJOC", "DLKC", "DVNC", "DKHC", "DLAC"));
 private static final ArrayList<String> MY_FIFTH_LIST = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("DKRC", "DTHC", "DTWC", "DILC", "DALC", "DSEC", "DTRC", "DZAC", "DARC", "DCOC", "DRUC", "DMYC", "DMXC", "DPKC", "DIDC", "DBRC", "DNPC", "DJOC", "DLKC", "DVNC", "DKHC", "DLAC"));

 public static final HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> MY_SECOND_MAP = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

 static {
     MY_SECOND_MAP.put("T1", MY_SECOND_LIST);
     MY_SECOND_MAP.put("T2", MY_THIRD_LIST);
     MY_SECOND_MAP.put("T3", MY_FOURTH_LIST);
     MY_SECOND_MAP.put("T4", MY_FIFTH_LIST);
 }     

}
```

When I access `MY_MAP.get("test1")` or `MY_MAP.get("test2")` or for that matter on any key on `MY_MAP`, I always get empty list. Looks like for some reason `MY_LIST` is initialized to empty list.

Can anyone tell in what rare case can this happen? This is constantly happening in production environment but am not able to reproduce this locally.

Environment details:

- Redhat Enterprise 5.3 Server 64-bit (Update U3)
- JDK7
- jvm options

> --FLApplication.machineProtocol=UDP -Dclient.encoding.override=UTF-8 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xmx512m -Xms512m -XX:SurvivorRatio=8 -XX:PermSize=128M -XX:MaxPermSize=128M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled

Comment: Production, seriously?

Comment: Please specify environment: OS, Java version, jvm options. Do you use multi threads?

Comment: When do you access the map?  Off the top of my head, I am thinking that maybe the `static` initializatiom block has not yet happened.

Comment: A simple `map.get("test1").clear()` anywhere in the codebase is all it takes to reproduce this. @TimBiegeleisen The only place where `static` init has not yet happened is static init itself.

Comment: Please describe the differences between the dev and prod environments. i.e. different tomcat versions can has this kind of affect.

Comment: You have two static ctors for the same class? perhaps you should have only one?

Comment: Also `public HashMap` is bad idea. You should use `Collections.unmodifiableMap()` for public field.

Comment: are you calling this `get` from a static block or static declaration/assignment ?

Comment: I am wondering to what level you simplified your code before you posted it here. Is all of this code really in 1 class. Or is it spread accross multiple classes ? (because that could certainly explain it).

Comment: PS: what's with the `new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(...))`. Are you doing this to make the list modifiable ? Or because you store it in an `ArrayList` reference. You know, it would make sense to replace all the `ArrayList<String>` references by simple `List<String>` references. And in that case, you can directly assign the `asList` returnvalue, without wrapping it in an additional `ArrayList`. I mean, it looks a bit clumsy. If you would ommit the wrapper and use the `asList` value, you would get exceptions if somebody tries to remove items from the list. That could in fact reveal the bug.

Comment: Are you really creating `MY_LIST` like that, in production, or is this just for testing? Maybe the list is actually read from some DB, and that DB is not yet ready?

Comment: Updated environments

Comment: @bvdb - code is bit clumsy, but not inaccurate, i dont have luxury to try out different things on production, but looking for real root cause if it can be identified, but I agree that code could have been better

Comment: @tobias_k - no, list is initialized this way, not from db

Comment: @Marko Topolnik : Identified the root cause by checking if there was remove/clear on the list. There was indeed remove all which will be called only in production. I will accept your answer if you can write it as anwer instead of comment.

Comment: @marco13 You shouldn't have deleted your answer because it is the right advice to OP and, had he written such code, he would never have the issue in the first place.

Comment: @Shiva Kumar I guess it could be a matter of code rules and company culture. But if we encounter a bug in production, then we allow code changes. Even if the code change is not strictly linked to the bug. I mean, we add exceptions, add log-entries, ... just to detect and avoid current and future issues.

Answer (score 0):

Posting on behalf of @Marko Topolnik and @marco13
It was what @Marko Topolnik suggested in one of his comments. There was indeed a removeAll statement which was reachable only in production which was actually emptying the list.

As @marco13 suggested, this issue would have been identified if only we created unmodifiable lists at the first place. So to avoid bumping into such issues, the code could be modified like below

```
     private static final List<String> MY_LIST = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList("DCNC", "DJPC", "DKRC", "DTHC", "DTWC", "DILC", "DALC", "DSEC", "DTRC", "DZAC", "DARC", "DCOC", "DRUC", "DMYC", "DMXC", "DPKC", "DIDC", "DBRC", "DNPC", "DJOC", "DLKC", "DVNC", "DKHC", "DLAC"));
```